Whats a suitable feature selection method for Time series data across multiple files?
My problem is basically a higher dimensional regression, where my input is (100 levels, 300 timesteps, 23 features)
My goal is to build a deep learning LSTM model that finds which level the data belongs to.
I split my training/test and validation data data (70, 300, 23)/(30, 300, 23)
My problem is that i want to reduce the 23 features, in this case they're columns in each level (which i represent by a stand alone file).
I have read about some feature selection methods, but they all seem to be for lower dimensional data. How can I find the most important features across all files and features?
